# How to setState from within a callback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, twilio, twilio-api, react-functional-component

I am trying to use Twilio's Chat Client SDK, which is under-documented, with React Hooks/FC. And am having an issue finding the correct way to update my state from the context of the `on` callback.

http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/

If I register it on every render, then naturally I get a memory leak and duplicate responses handling.

```
const MessageList = ({channel}) => {
  const [messageGroups, setMessageGroups] = React.useState([]);

  ...

    channel.on("messageAdded", (message) => {
    if(messageGroups.length == 0) {
      setMessageGroups([[message]])
      return
    }

    let messageChucks = [...messageGroups]

    ...

    setMessageGroups(messageChucks)
  })
```

If I register it in a `useEffect` than the `messageGroups` value is statically defined to the value it had when the `useEffect` was last triggered meaning that `messageGroups` get resets to empty. I could then update my `useEffect` to reregister on `MessageGroups` change, but that would just be a slower memory leak.

```
const MessageList = ({channel}) => {
  const [messageGroups, setMessageGroups] = React.useState([]);

  ...

  React.useEffect(() => {
    channel.on("messageAdded", (message) => {
      if(messageGroups.length == 0) {
        setMessageGroups([[message]])
        return
      }

      let messageChucks = [...messageGroups]

      ...
 
      setMessageGroups(messageChucks)
    })
  }, [channel])
```

Is there a way to have my callback as registered use the latest state, or another way to work around this?

Comment: subscription to the events should happen only once. but here, the `useEffect` is getting called every time the `channel` is updated. can you try replacing `[channel]` with `[]` ?

Comment: It needs to be reregistered anytime the channel is changed, which right now is zero. The issue is after it's registered the context of messageGroups doesn't update on rerenders after even though its been populated with history

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the answer is to pass the function into the `setState` which gives you the previous state, this then allows you to update the state and return it.

```
  const handleMessageAdded = (message) => {
    setMessageGroups(prevMessageGroups => {
      if(prevMessageGroups.length == 0) {
        return [[message]]
      }

      let messageChucks = [...prevMessageGroups]

      ...

      return messageChucks
    })
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    channel.on("messageAdded", handleMessageAdded)
  }, [channel])
```